# Eclipse can't find .wav file

Tags: java, file

Java always returns

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \Beep.wav (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at bombTimer.BombTimer.<init>(BombTimer.java:36)
at bombTimer.BombTimer.main(BombTimer.java:87)
```

Here's the code I'm using

```
import sun.audio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class BombTimer extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private AudioStream audioStream1=null;
private AudioStream audioStream2=null;
public BombTimer(){
    try {
        audioStream1=new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("/Beep.wav"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've set the classpath a million times it doesn't change anything
I copied the text and compiled it from the command line and it works there.

## The problem went away when I made a completely new project and copied over all the text.

I'm still not satisfied, but now it runs

Comment: Are you sure it's not `beep.wav`? Are you sure the file is in the right folder? What OS are you running this on? Are you sure ... [insert 1000 things here]? What I'm trying to say is that we have no way of telling you the answer if you don't give us your directory structure, etc...

Comment: The file is in \Workspace\BombTimer.I run everything off JRE7 in Eclipse

Comment: There's your problem. It should be in `/Workspace/BombTimer/src/`.

Comment: I've had it there to, doesn't work

Comment: ah, never mind, I found your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7217260/1223693). although I don't know why putting it in `src` didn't work. Are you sure it's named `Beep.wav` with a capital `B`?

Comment: I made a `resources` folder, still does not work. It is with a capital B

Comment: You followed exactly what it said in the link I posted? That probably means you configured something wrong somewhere, and there is absolutely no way for us to find out what since we don't have access to your computer.

Comment: I have my Workspace in a file in documents, does that affect anything?

Answer (score 1):

OK i think because it is not relative path when we start a path with / it is considered as absolute path so if you want to find your file keep the file in the same package as your java file and make sure that , the file is copied in the bin folder as well when you build the project now you would be able to access the file by writing this statement.

```
audioStream1=new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("Beep.wav"));
```

Comment: Tried it, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the file not in src/ but in the general project folder.

Comment: Just to make sure after every one of these changes, you  might need to Build the project again under Project > Build. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929415/where-do-you-put-input-file-in-eclipsejava-in-order-to-read-it-from-console-co

Answer (score 1):

Try loading your wav as an InputStream from the classpath.

There are a few ways to do this but this might work.

```
audioStream1=new AudioStream(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Beep.wav"));
```

It looks like what you have done is provided an absolute path to the filesystem, so the way you have written your code, your classpath is being completely ignored.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `File` object, it will not read from classpath. So you need to keep `.wav` file in your project root folder. For ex;

```
c:\javaproj\Beep.wav
```

or

You need to mention the absolute path of your file in your code.

```
try {
    audioStream1=new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("c:/javaproj/src/Beep.wav")); // location of file
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I need to export this to a JAR and email it though...