# Can't load javaFX Image

Tags: java, image, javafx

I'm having some troubles to load images in javaFX from the controller.

I put some images in the src/ folder and even in a folder img/ but still getting "Invalid URL or resource not found".

My directory is like

```
src/
    package/
      javaFXcontroller.java
      img/
         image.png
```

So I'm doing `Image img = new Image("./img/image.png");`

But I can't retrieve the image "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found"

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `new Image("/img/image.png")`.

Comment: Thanks but It doesn't work either..

Comment: Is the `src` directory marked as a resources directory by your IDE? Are you using a build tool such as Maven or Gradle? Make sure `image.png` is included in the build output and added to the classpath/modulepath at runtime.

Comment: I'm not using Gradle or Maven unfortunalety. I just dragged images from my folder into the package of eclipse

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Eclipse. These questions may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7217228/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934796/

Comment: Thanks you @Slaw but I found what I wanted. For those who may encounter the same problem, just drag your images into the src/ folder directly with eclipse and then require your image with the path new Image("image.png").

Comment: Consider posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

For those who may encounter the same problem, just drag your images into the src/ folder directly with eclipse and then require your image with the path new Image("image.png").